# Which PHP extension implements shm_attach?

Tags: php, shared-memory

I tried on various platforms ,but all reports a fatal error says this function doesn't exist.

Which extension should I enable?

Comment: One advise, If any built in function create issue or not clear to you go with php manual http://php.net/manual/en/. That will solve your problems guaranteed by 99.99%

Comment: Not a criticism, just for curiosity, why do you need that function in php?

Answer (score 1):

The [Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php) extension. The required compile switches are [here](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php).

Comment: +1. @compile-fan not meant as an RTFM, but those things can always be found in the parent chapter of the function's manual page (if it's documented in the PHP manual).

Comment: Do you mean a single function(`shm_attach`) requires 3 extension to implement?

Comment: @compile Read it carefully. The shared memory part requires `sysvshm`. The reason it's grouped with, technically, other extensions in the manual is because they're typically used together.